# If the system Ax=b is consistent for every n x 1 matrix in b, then A is invertible.

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I have trouble understanding the proof here. I spent an hour trying to understand it but I give up. Can anyone help me with it?

[image]

Comment: 1) Yes, that's exactly what it is. The point is that if you can solve $A{\mathbf x}={\mathbf b}$ for any ${\mathbf b}$, you can solve it for ${\mathbf b}$ equal to any of the various columns of the identity matrix.  2) They mean to build a *matrix* $C$ out of the columns that form the solutions in part 1). Since matrix multiplication is done one column at a time, that gives you a matrix that gives you all the right columns to get the identity matrix, so they produced an inverse for $A$.

Comment: I think I kind of get it. In matrix C, it isn't just 1 x n matrix right? It's n x n matrix, where each column has n rows. Basically n unknowns. And we take matrix A multiply by this n column to give us a column on the identity matrix. And then we repeat again to get column of the identity matrix. And then we combine them to form an augmented matrix, which really is an identity matrix. And from there we prove the rest. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah, I think that's pretty much the point. I wouldn't really call it an augmented matrix, but otherwise you're right on.

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning, they're saying that since $Ax = b$ is consistent no matter which vector $b$ is, then in particular the system
\begin{equation}
Ax = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
is consistent.  In other words, there exists a vector $x_1$ such that
\begin{equation}
Ax_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

And, since $Ax = b$ is consistent no matter what $b$ is, it must be true that the system
\begin{equation}
Ax = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
is consistent.  In other words, there exists a vector $x_2$ such that
\begin{equation}
Ax_2 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
And so on.  Now take these vectors $x_1, x_2,\ldots$ and make them the columns of a matrix $C$:
\begin{equation}
C = \begin{bmatrix} x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_n \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
You can check that $AC = I$, the identity matrix.  So $A$ is invertible.